# Extend (C:) Drive while Recovery Partition in between and unable to transfer files

Tags: windows, partitioning, disk-space

My `C:` drive is completely filled up, and now I want to allocate some more storage space to it.

Disk Management showing my Disk Memory allocations:
[image: Disk Management showing my Disk Memory allocations]

[NOTE] I'll be shrinking (D:) to get unallocated space, which will be given out to the right side of (D:) Drive.

There is this "Recovery Partition" between (C:) and (D:) Drive due to which I'm unable to add unallocated space to (C:) drive ("Extend Volume" option being grayed-out) and I'm not sure whether it is safe to remove that Recovery Partition.

Moreover, even if I do remove that "Recovery Partition", I do not want to copy files from (D:) drive to another new drive for formatting the (D:) drive and deleting that drive because I don't know whether moving these files will break my computer or not.

Files in (D:) Drive:
[image: Files in (D:) Drive]

Please guide me to add space to my (C:) Drive in this scenario.

(What I tried): I tried using AOMEI Partition Assistant for merging partition but found out that option being grayed-out as well.

Comment: AOMEI Partition Assistant or similar solutions can move the partition so existing partitions can be extended. You will want to disable (not suspend) BitLocker protection

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Which Unallocated space are you trying to add? In the Disk Management screenshot, all space seems to be allocated.

Comment: It is unadvisable to delete your recovery partition. If you have free space in your D:\ drive, you should shrink it, move it to the  right  and then move the recovery partition to the right. Then you would have space to expand C:\. I also echo the need to disable bitlocker to accomplish such task. While you are free to use whatever partition assistant you want, I personally recommend Ubuntu Live gparted to resize and move partitions.

Comment: I get the feeling this Q is asked every week, https://superuser.com/search?q=Extend+%28C%3A%29+Drive+

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I think that his question is a bit more nuanced, since it's not only about extending to non-contiguous unallocated space,  but also about the Recovery partition and D: partition

Comment: @YisroelTech - It really isn’t and this question is ask weekly

Comment: Plenty of those type scenarios turn up in search as well.

Comment: I see zero unallocated space. And it's pretty risky while gains are marginal (1.3 GB or so). I have no idea what he wants.

Comment: No matter what course of action they choose he will need to offload some of his data onto another disk temporarily.

Comment: Sorry about that. Now I did mention from where I would be gettting unallocated space.

Comment: @OTUin - You can’t merge two partitions. You can only merge a partition with a file system and adjacent and an unallocated partition. You will have to follow the duplicate to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you seemingly have system files on the `D:` partition, and you don't know exactly what and where they were set to be there, I would advise you to leave the `D:` partition up and running and not mess with what's on it (let's say a program runs from the `D:` partition, how will it now know to run from the `C:` partition?)

Instead, you should:

1. **Shrink** the `D:` partition (let's say by *100 GB* from the 167 of free space on it) using the **Shrink Volume** in Disk Management (or with AOMEI Partition Assistant)
2. Extend the `C:` partition to all the newly created Unallocated space using the **Merge Partitions** option in ***AOMEI Partition Assistant*** (since Disk Management would not allow you to extend to non-contiguous unallocated space) by select *Merge Partitions* from the right-click menu of the `C:` partition and select the Unallocated 'partition' in the popup window. (You can also do the same with most 3rd party partition manager tools, I personally like [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/resizepartition/how-to-extend-partition-to-non-contiguous-space.html))

Comment: Here's what it is showing when I used AOMEI Partition Assistant after unallocating space from (D:) Drive:-
Right-clicking on (C:) Drive and advanced options, Merge Partition being disabled

Comment: Can you edit your question and share a screenshot of that?

Comment: @OTUin - You have to shrink a partition in order to create a adjacent unallocated partition in order to merge the two partitions

Comment: @Ramhound - I did shrink a partition and create an unallocated space but I cannot use Merge Partition options as you can see in the third image link I have extended

Comment: @OTUin - You created an unallocated partition but it’s not adjacent to the partition you want to merge with it.

Comment: @Ramhound - Yeah, that's the part where I don't know what to do and hence asking for help.